# mobx - view logic on stores

Tags: reactjs, mobx

I have a very large app on mobx + react, where many components call the same actions on store. For example, "delete photo", can be call from a list of photos or from a modal. But before execute the action I have, for example, to show a confirmation modal...

I end-up with this soluction, but it looks like that I'm mixin data login with view logic...

```
class PhotoStore {
  @observable photos;

  @action destroy(photo) {
    if (currentUser.isGuest) {
      modalStore.open('NoGuest')
      return
    }

    modalStore.openConfirm(() => {
      // some datalogic
      api.delete('/photos/'+photo.id).then(() => {
        notificationStore.showSuccess('your photo was deleted!')
      })
    })
  }
}


const PhotoView = observer(({photo}) => {
  return <div onClick={() => photoStore.destroy(photo)}>...</div>
})
```

What so you thing? is that ok to go?

thanks a lot!

Comment: looks good. Maybe a typo. should be `photoStore.destroy(photo)`

Comment: also the parent component to PhotoView should be an `@observer`.

Comment: yes, it is just a example ;) I'll fix it

Answer (score 0):

To avoid UI logic with model logic, the code can be simplified as follows.

```
class PhotoView extends React.Component {
  handleDelete() {
    if (this.props.currentUser.isGuest) {
      modalStore.open('NoGuest');
      return;
    }

    modalStore.openConfirm(() => {
      // some datalogic
      photoStore.delete(this.props.photo).then(() => {
        notificationStore.showSuccess('your photo was deleted!');
      });
    });
  }

  render() {
    return <div onClick={this.handleDelete.bind(this)}>...</div>
  }
}
```

The delete function on the PhotoStore should be modified:

```
@action delete(photo) {
  return new Promise((res, rej) => {
    api.delete('/photos/'+photo.id)
       .then(res)
       .catch(rej);
  });
}
```

Comment: Yes, ok... but if I have to call the same action from ANOTHER component, I'll replicate handleDelete... or move it high on my component structure and pass it down

Comment: It depends. handleDelete and Button/Div could be grouped together to form another component.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

notificationStore.showSuccess('your photo was deleted!')

You could add an observable to store and modify it there. Your modal code could live somewhere else and be an observer